# Как реализовать hover?

Tags: html, css

может кто видел, как реализовать такой hover эффект? Или подскажет-поможет реализовать.
[тык](https://dox.forqy.website/shop/)

Comment: Эффект -- Recent News

Comment: На каком элементе? Какой эффект? Как это должно выглядеть? Куда смотреть? Вы уже пытались? Что не получилось? Приведите пожалуйста минимальным, самодостаточный и воспроизводительный пример проблемы.

Comment: Я не пытался, я не понимаю, как сделать блок поверх изображения, там в recent news, когда наводишь на изображение, вылетает блок

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: url("https://dox.forqy.website/shop/wp-content/uploads/sites/33/2018/01/dox-tech-03-800x533.jpg");
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main:hover .text {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1d1d1d;
  height: 60%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: .3s ease-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо pза это!

Comment: А можно как-нибудь самому изображение вставлять, в html?

Comment: Можно. Уберите background и добавьте `<img src="https://dox.forqy.website/shop/wp-content/uploads/sites/33/2018/01/dox-tech-03-800x533.jpg">` в main.

Comment: Спасибо вам, помогли!